# Java - Sorting a Set of Points Based on Both X and Y Coordinates

Tags: java, sorting, point, comparator

I have a list of point objects that need to be sorted by both X and Y coordinates, but when I pass them to a comparator object only one coordinate gets sorted (the first one called). Any ideas to why this might be happening?

```
static public List<Point> convertToThreeByThreeGrid(String points) {
    String[] ptsArray;
    List<Point> ptsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String stripString = points.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", ",").trim();
    ptsArray = stripString.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < ptsArray.length; i += 2) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(ptsArray[i]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(ptsArray[i + 1]);
        System.out.println("X: " + x);
        System.out.println("Y: " + y);
        ptsList.add(new Point(x, y));
    }

    Collections.sort(ptsList, new Comparator<Point>() {
        public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
            int result = Integer.compare((int) a.getX(), (int) b.getX());
            if (result == 0 ) {
                result = Integer.compare((int) a.getY(), (int) b.getY());
            }
            return result;
        }
    });

   // subtract each coordinate by smallest x and y coordinate values
    List<Point> convertedPtList = new ArrayList<>();
    int smallestX = (int) ptsList.get(0).getX();
    int smallestY = (int) ptsList.get(0).getY();
    for (int i = 1; i < ptsList.size(); i++) {
        int x = ((int) ptsList.get(i).getX() - smallestX);
        int y = ((int) ptsList.get(i).getY() - smallestY);
        convertedPtList.add(new Point(x, y));
    }
    return convertedPtList;

  }
}
```

Output:

[java.awt.Point[x=10,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=10,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=10,y=28], java.awt.Point[x=12,y=26]]

[java.awt.Point[x=13,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=13,y=28], java.awt.Point[x=13,y=28], java.awt.Point[x=14,y=27], java.awt.Point[x=14,y=27], java.awt.Point[x=15,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=15,y=28], java.awt.Point[x=15,y=28]]

[java.awt.Point[x=16,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=16,y=28], java.awt.Point[x=16,y=28], java.awt.Point[x=18,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=18,y=26], java.awt.Point[x=18,y=28]]

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some sample input/output?

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling sortXCoordinates and sortYCoordinates, as these comparators only sort on one axis.

Comment: Why you have 2 Comparators instead of comparing X and Y in one Comparator with an priorisation?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How should the result look like?

Comment: I just need sorted  X/Y point objects....

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i < ptsArray.length; i += 2) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(ptsArray[i]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(ptsArray[i+1]);
    ptsList.add(new Point(x, y));
}

Collections.sort( ptsList, new Comparator<Point>() {
       public int compare(Point x1, Point x2) {
         int result = Double.compare(x1.getX(), x2.getX());
         if ( result == 0 ) {
           // both X are equal -> compare Y too
           result = Double.compare(x1.getY(), x2.getY());
         } 
         return result;
      }
    });

// ptsList is now sorted by both X and Y!
```

**Edit:**

To just find the lowest X and the lowest Y you can also go the 'classic' way without any (double-)sorting:

```
int minX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int minY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for ( Point p : ptsList ) {

  final int x = (int)p.getX();
  final int y = (int)p.getY();

  if ( x < minX ) {
    minX = x;
  } 

  if ( y < minY ) {
    minY = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and the Y coordinates still aren't sorting... Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Of course, you must only sort your list *once*! Do *one* sort with the above `Comparator` and the list is then sorted by both X and Y (in that order). - If you want to sort by Y, then X, just swap the `getX()` and `getY()` calls in the comparator. If you want the sort order reversed, swap `x1` and `x2` in the `Double.compare(...)` calls.

Comment: Quick question: Why are you checking if the result == 0? Some of my point sets have multiple x coordinates that have the same value. Could you please explain?

Comment: I have to ask back: Do you want *a single list* where points are sorted by both X and Y, or do you need *two* lists, where one is sorted by X only and the other one is sorted by Y only? - I was assuming the first case, as that's what one wants most of the time.

Comment: I tried your example above and the Y coordinates still aren't sorting. Here's an example output of a point set that isn't being sorted: [java.awt.Point[x=22,y=25], java.awt.Point[x=23,y=23], java.awt.Point[x=23,y=24], java.awt.Point[x=23,y=24], java.awt.Point[x=23,y=24], java.awt.Point[x=24,y=25]]

Comment: This shouldn't happen. By the way, try to replace `Double.compare()` with `Integer.compare()` because we're working with `int`s here.

Comment: Do you see in my example that there are multiple x coordinates with the same value? Why should I be testing if the result == 0?

Comment: Because if you don't, all points with equal X will be considered to be completely equal w.r.t. sort order and those points will end up without any particular order in their Y values. Or, in other words, if the comparator says that two objects are "equal" by returning 0 those two objects will be sorted in a random order between them. To sort by X *and* Y this should only happen if X *and* Y are equal between the two points. That's why the comparator above will *only* return 0 when x1.x == x2.x *and* x1.y == x2.y.

Comment: I see... Yeah, for some reason the Y coordinates aren't being sorted... Is there another method that I could use to sort my points?

Comment: "I tried your example above and the Y coordinates still aren't sorting" -- I cannot see how this would be possible. To me it looks like the output you posted does not match the code. - Did you still call `sortXCoordinates()` before outputting?

Comment: No, I've completely removed that method... I've updated my code to include the whole method call...

Comment: I've tried the code myself now, and it's working as expected.

Comment: I see your updated code `int smallestX = (int) ptsList.get(0).getX(); int smallestY = (int) ptsList.get(0).getY();`. This won't work. Example: If I put into the list only two points [0,1] and [1,0], how should the list return to me a point [0,0] which is what you are looking for.

Comment: What you could do is `sortXCoordinates(ptsList); int smallestX = (int) ptsList.get(0).getX(); sortYCoordinates(ptsList); int smallestY = (int) ptsList.get(0).getY();`.

Comment: If a list is sorted by both x and y coordinates then shouldn't the first x and y points be the lowest values?

Comment: No, because the list will only contain exactly those objects you put into it before. A `Point` is *one* object, containing a value for X and one for Y. Sorting the *list* only changes the order of *objects* in the list but does not change the values *inside* those objects.